# Is it Better to Leave a Comment or Pose a New Question Asking for Elaboration?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sometimes after I receive a good answer to a question, the poster will leave an additional suggestion for me as they have done for [my most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203917/is-randomoversampler-causing-my-model-to-overfit). This sparks my curiosity, and I would like them to elaborate further. But I want to make sure I don't steer the post off topic in doing so. Would it be better to frame this request as a separate question or simply leave a comment asking for more information?

Comment: By all means open a [chat-room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (link to open new room at the bottom) and hash something out, but comments are ephemeral as you know and we don't function well hosting discussions. If it leads to a new question then all the better for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post it as a new question.  You can include a link back to the original to make the context clear, but it's not necessary.

Comment: They should put what is needed to ask their question in their post, not just at a link.